# Proving differentiability of a complex function

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives

Prove that if $f(z)$ is differentiable at $z_0$ then:

$f(z)=f(z_0)+f'(z_0)(z-z_0)+\lambda(z)(z-z_0)$, where $\lambda(z)\to 0$ as $z\to z_0$.

We begin by the definition:

\begin{equation}
f'(z_0)=\lim_{\Delta z\to 0}\frac{f(z_0+\Delta z)-f(z_0)}{\Delta z}
\end{equation}

Then to:

\begin{equation}
\lim_{\Delta z\to 0}f'(z_0)\Delta z=\lim_{\Delta z\to 0}f(z_0+\Delta z)-f(z_0)
\end{equation}

set $\Delta z=(z-z_0)$ on the left side of =

\begin{equation}
\lim_{(z-z_0)\to 0}f'(z_0)(z-z_0)=\lim_{\Delta z\to 0}[f(z_0+\Delta z)-f(z_0)]
\end{equation}

But this is not the given results above.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131975/discussion-on-question-by-vqngs-proving-differentiability-of-a-complex-function).

Comment: You cannot just move $\Delta z$ to the other side because it is changing ($\Delta z\to 0$). You have to introduce $\lim_{\Delta z\to 0}$ on the left-hand side as well then. In that way of course you will get nowhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $f$ is defined in some neighbourhood $D$ of $z_0 \in \mathbb C$ and is differentiable at $z_0$. Let us define $\lambda : D \to \mathbb C$ by
$$
\lambda (z): = \frac{{f(z) - f(z_0 )}}{{z - z_0 }} - f'(z_0 )
$$
if $D \ni z\neq z_0$ and $\lambda(z_0):=0$. Then by re-arranging the definition,
$$f(z)=f(z_0)+f'(z_0)(z-z_0)+\lambda(z)(z-z_0).$$
It is clear from the definition of $f'(z_0)$ that $\lim_{z\to z_0}\lambda(z)=0$.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I find frustrating about calculus, one always have to fish things out of nowhere.

Comment: I think it is quite obvious in this case. You are given $\lambda$ just have to solve for it.

Comment: Thanks for this, I will have to read it through many times!